# How to run complete Haskell program

Tags: macos, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and understand how to run a short script. However, I'm trying to run this program: https://github.com/bollu/cellularAutomata. This program has an app folder with Main.hs, a source folder, and some shell scripts.

How do you run this from terminal?

Currently firing up GHCi, loading Main.hs and not being able to run it.

This is the error I get right now when I load Main straight from the app.

```
Prelude> :cd /Users/name/Downloads/code library/cellularAutomata-master/app
Prelude> :load Main
[1 of 8] Compiling Cyclic1D         ( Cyclic1D.hs, interpreted )

Cyclic1D.hs:7:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘Cellular’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
7 | import Cellular
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

In total, it can't find 6 modules.

--EDIT--

After installing cabal and stack and running

`stack build`

I receive this error halfway through the build:

```
setup: The program 'pkg-config' version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not be found.
```

Ideas? Originally I thought pkg-config came with cairo, so I spent time putting symlinks to that, but now I believe perhaps pkg-config should come with either stack or the original project.

Looking through the error logs this error shows while trying to compile StackSetupShim for both `cairo-0.13.3.1` and `glib-0.13.4.1`, sample one for the latter below:

````
      /private/var/folders/1l/0993c3212tg_93l0d4ypfk1m0000gn/T/stack-215ef039e4c6f639/glib-0.13.4.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup [...] --dependency=utf8-string=utf8-string-1.0.1.1-1DpjxLeTvGg7ttZZojxJR5
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
    Logs have been written to: /Users/name/stack/cellularAutomata/.stack-work/logs/glib-0.13.4.1.log

    [1 of 2] Compiling Main             ( /private/var/folders/1l/0993c3212tg_93l0d4ypfk1m0000gn/T/stack-215ef039e4c6f639/glib-0.13.4.1/Setup.hs, /private/var/folders/1l/0993c3212tg_93l0d4ypfk1m0000gn/T/stack-215ef039e4c6f639/glib-0.13.4.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/Main.o )
    [2 of 2] Compiling StackSetupShim   ( /Users/name/.stack/setup-exe-src/setup-shim-mPHDZzAJ.hs, /private/var/folders/1l/0993c3212tg_93l0d4ypfk1m0000gn/T/stack-215ef039e4c6f639/glib-0.13.4.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/StackSetupShim.o )
    Linking /private/var/folders/1l/0993c3212tg_93l0d4ypfk1m0000gn/T/stack-215ef039e4c6f639/glib-0.13.4.1/.stack-work/dist/x86_64-osx/Cabal-1.24.2.0/setup/setup ...
    Configuring glib-0.13.4.1...
    setup: The program 'pkg-config' version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not
    be found.```
````

Comment: Open your terminal and type `cabal install`? It seems that you have missing dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

This project uses [Haskell Stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) for managing dependencies. It can be installed with `brew install stack` if you're using homebrew, or by following the instructions in the Stack documentation.

Once installed, you can run the shell scripts, eg `./build-and-ghci.sh`, which will use Stack to download ghc, the project dependencies, and then start ghci.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a bit, but now I am running into issues with finding 'pkg-config'. I receive this error ```setup: The program 'pkg-config' version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not
    be found.``` while configuring both ```glib-0.13.4.1``` and ```cairo-0.13.3.1```. Edited post likewise.

Comment: Please do not use the comments for new questions.

Comment: Finally figured it out... first `brew install program` whatever program came up as missing, and then override OS X's tendency to not automatically configure symlinks by using `export  PKG_CONFIG_PATH=path:path:path` for every `pkgconfig` folder I found in my cellar. More here: https://github.com/JustinTulloss/zeromq.node/issues/283#issuecomment-51431863